# Change UIImageView.image with delay

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, function, swift2

Okay, so I'm trying to create a "slideshow" of sorts by creating a class that would store an array of `UIImages`, and have a function that would choose a random index from the array and then assign the associate image to the image view in `ViewController.h`

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var audioPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1-08 Patient Love", ofType: "mp3")!)
var playPauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem()
var musicPaused: Bool = false

@IBOutlet var toolbar: UIToolbar!  
@IBOutlet var bg1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bg2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bg3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bg4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bg5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bg6: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bg7: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bg8: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bg9: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bg10: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bg11: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioPath)}
    catch {
            print("Audio file not found.")
        }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func playPause(sender: UIBarButtonItem){

    var items = toolbar.items!

    if musicPaused == false {

        playPauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "playPause:")

        items[0] = playPauseBtn

        toolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)

        audioPlayer.play()
        musicPaused = true

    }else{

        var items = toolbar.items!

        playPauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "playPause:")
        items [0] = playPauseBtn
        toolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)

        audioPlayer.pause()
        musicPaused = false
    }
}

@IBAction func stopButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var items = toolbar.items!
    audioPlayer.stop()
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
    playPauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "playPause:")
    items[0] = playPauseBtn
    toolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)
    musicPaused = false
}
}
```

This is my view controller.swift file. I don't have a reference yet to the function I'm trying to write in a slideshow.swift file here

```
import UIKit

var imageArray: [UIImage] = [
UIImage(named: "dec11.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "dec18.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "dec19.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "dec19-2.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "dec24.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "dec25.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "dec30.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "jan1.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "jan20.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "jan24.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "jan30.jpg")!
]
```

The slideshow class is

```
class slideshow: NSObject {

func changeImage() -> UIImage{
    //wait 2 secs
    let seconds = 2.0
    let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
    let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        //here code perfomed with delay
        //generate random number
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(11))

        var imageAtIndex = imageArray[randomIndex]

        return imageAtIndex
    })
}
}
```

Would it be easier to just write this all in view controller? I changed the function declaration as per the suggestion of other users, but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two declarations of the variable `image`. You have one that is passed into the function:

```
@IBAction func changeImage (image: UIImage){
```

And another that is part of your delayed action:

```
    //return image at index
    var image = imageAtIndex
```

You don't want to return the image, you want to set the image property of the `UIImageView` to the image from the array, assuming your array contains `UIImage`.

So change your function decalaration to be

```
func changeImage (imageViewToChange: UIImageView){
```

Then change the `dispatch_after` code to be

```
dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

    //here code performed after delay
    //generate random number
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(11))

    //return image at index
    imageViewToChange.image = imageArray[randomIndex]
})
```

Comment: Awesome! This at least got me an image on screen. I then tried to add another dispatch after statement to delay and then make it recursive. That also did not work. Ideas on that?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to call `changeImage()` after you set the image? Inside the `dispatch_after`, simply call `self.changeImage( imageViewToChange)`

Answer (score 0):

The following code is untested but you should be able to do something like the following.  The slideshow class contains the list of possible images with a start and stop method.  The animate method calls recursively so you don't have to call it from your vc every time.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var audioPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1-08 Patient Love", ofType: "mp3")!)
var playPauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem()
var musicPaused: Bool = false

@IBOutlet var toolbar: UIToolbar!  
@IBOutlet var bg: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioPath)}
    catch {
            print("Audio file not found.")
        }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func playPause(sender: UIBarButtonItem){

    var items = toolbar.items!

    if musicPaused == false {

        playPauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "playPause:")

        items[0] = playPauseBtn

        toolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)

        audioPlayer.play()
        musicPaused = true
        slideshow.startSlideshow(bg)

    }else{

        var items = toolbar.items!

        playPauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "playPause:")
        items [0] = playPauseBtn
        toolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)

        audioPlayer.pause()
        slideshow.stopSlideshow()
        musicPaused = false
    }
}

@IBAction func stopButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var items = toolbar.items!
    audioPlayer.stop()
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
    playPauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "playPause:")
    items[0] = playPauseBtn
    toolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)
    musicPaused = false
    slideshow.stopSlideshow()
}
}


class slideshow: NSObject {

var imageArray: [UIImage] = [
UIImage(named: "dec11.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "dec18.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "dec19.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "dec19-2.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "dec24.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "dec25.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "dec30.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "jan1.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "jan20.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "jan24.jpg")!,
UIImage(named: "jan30.jpg")!
]
var shouldAnimate: boolean?

func startSlideshow(imageView: UIImageView) {
    shouldAnimate = true
    self.animate()
}

func stopSlideshow() {
    shouldAnimate = false
}

func animate() {
        //wait 2 secs
    let seconds = 2.0
    let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
    let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        //here code perfomed with delay
        //generate random number
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(11))

        var imageAtIndex = imageArray[randomIndex]

        imageView.image = imageAtIndex
        if (shouldAnimate) {
          self.animate()
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed the declaration of my function to match this, but I'm still getting the same error. Maybe it's the way I have the array declared.

Comment: No, changeImage is supposed to change the image being displayed after a X second delay.  His error is that he has two declarations of the variable image.  One as a parameter, and one in the function.

Comment: If wottle is correct in what you're trying to do then you'd need access to the image view to set the image equal to.  But maybe you can update your method and maybe show the code that is calling it to give us more context.

Comment: I've edited to show my view controller.swift as well as the slideshow.swift class I'm trying to write. I've been working on this small app as a gift for a few days, and I feel like I'm missing something. Am I taking the wrong approach here? The idea is that the play pause buttons will cause a slideshow to start with the music, and delay it when pause is pressed.

Comment: A few things to note, first it doesn't look like you'll need all of those image views.  You should be able to adjust the image on one image view each time.  If you use the method that wottle has put in his answer you could pass bg1 into that method and it will change the image after x seconds.

Comment: ChrisHooked I just updated this answer to provide some recursion that might help avoid figuring out calling changeImage.  Let me know if this helps or if you have any questions about the implementation.

Comment: Hey, you're awesome. This code got me a working slideshow. There was an issue with shouldAnimate being of type boolean. I suppose it's not supported in Swift 2, but I changed a few things around and got the show going.... Adding the stopShow function to the pause button didn't work as expected, but I just broke up with the girl I was working on this for, so I don't really need to continue working on it lol.